# Redis client in decoupled node.js app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, redis

Hi I am using redis in a node.js app for user caching. After the user has been loged-in, the user information is cached, and accessed on every other request to determine what access the user has and the client receives information, views etc. based on that. 
Right now the app creates a redisClient at the beginning and passes that to the needed express route callbacks(which is pretty much all of them). To be honest I don't really like the extra argument that is being passed everywhere - especially when it is the same. 
Is there a better way to do it, and for instance if I a initialise the redisClient in every module will it have extra overhead

```
var express = require('express'),
    loginFunctionality = require('./routes/login'),
    homeFunctionality = require('./routes/home')
    ...

// Connect to redis
var redisClient = redis.createClient();
redisClient.on("error", function(err){
    console.log("An error occurred with redis:" + err);
});
... 


app.get('/', homeFunctionality.home);

app.post('/register', loginFunctionality.createNewUser);

app.post('/login', loginFunctionality.login(redisClient, secret));
...
```

what I am wondering is, if there is a good way to remove the redisClient parameter.

Comment: please put a sample of code... your question is not clear

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can pass the client along with every request through a middleware:

```
// initialization
var client = redis.createClient(...);

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  req.redis = client;
  next();
});

// a route handler
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  req.redis.get(...);
  ...
});
```

Or, if applicable, you could create a more elaborate middleware that would perform the cache lookups itself and pass the user data along with the request, so you don't have to perform the lookup in each request handler.

Or you could move the Redis client initialization to a separate module and require that from each of the files you need it:

```
// redis-client.js
var redis = require('redis');
module.exports = redis.createClient(...);

// elsewhere
var client = require('./redis-client');

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  client.get(...);
  ...
});
```

---

added on JAN 16th, 2019

Remember that with this technique, you can easily shut down the connection if something (like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) disconnects your server, simply by adding the `client.quit()`.

```
process.on('SIGTERM', () => {
  if (client) {
    console.log('Ending CACHE connection');
    client.quit();
  }
  console.log('Closing server...');
  app.close(() => {
    console.log('server was closed!');
    process.exit(0);
  });
});
```

Comment: All the callbacks I use for the routes are in different modules - login related, item related etc.
As for the second suggestion when you call it like that in different modules, won't it create a new instance for each module it was called from?(and if so, will it not create new connections)

Comment: Even if your callbacks are in different modules, they still get passed the `req` object (I assume), so they can use `req.redis` (adding properties to `req` is a nice way of propagating stuff down the middleware/routing chain). The second example uses the fact [that modules get cached](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching) after they are `require()`'d for the first time, so they would all share the same Redis client instance.